# Create a Different 403 Error Page For File Types?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mp3, http-status-code-403

Kind of a noob question to ask, but I was wondering if there was a different 403 error page for each type of file.

For example, if someone tries to access a php file, they would get something like:

```
403 Access Denied
```

Pretty generic error.

But, if they tried to access an mp3 file, the error would give:

```
Mp3 files are not available for download, Please go to the main site to stream music
```

Something like this is what I'm looking for.

**EDIT 2/11/15**

So after doing different attempts, I just made another htaccess for the music folder. But apparently forcing a 403 Error not only prevents the access of that music in the folder, but music won't load on the site. So the real question I guess would be how to prevent users from accessing mp3 files?

I just thought I'd post this in case anyone ever saw it. **When placed on mp3's, a 403 Error prevents the use of music files on the entire site.**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
header('HTTP/ 403 Mp3 files are not available for download, Please go to the main site to stream music');
```